# How to add SceneBuilder to Intellij after mistakenly adding the SceneBuilder's shortcut link

Tags: intellij-idea, scenebuilder

So I installed [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for the first time and I mistakenly linked [SceneBuilder's](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) shortcut link to the `FXML` file and keep getting this error: `IntelliJ failed to start scene builder`. After doing a lot of searching, I could not find out how to reset SceneBuilder. How do I reset SceneBuilder in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to follow this instruction to find the files I needed to edit. -> [Instructions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

I use Windows 10 so I used `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>`. My path looks like `C:\Users\yourUserName\.IdeaIC2017.3\config`. Next, I searched for "scenebulder". The results lead me to a file named "options" and a file named "other".

other.xml

```
<application>
  <component name="JavaFxSettings">
    <!-- change here --><option name="pathToSceneBuilder" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Gluon/SceneBuilder.lnk" />
    <!-- change here --><option name="myPathToSceneBuilder" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Gluon/SceneBuilder.lnk" />
  </component>
</application>
```

options.xml

```
<application>
  <component name="PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="Default.savedEditorTheme" value="_@user_Default" />
    <property name="installed.kotlin.plugin.version" value="1.2.10-release-IJ2017.3-1" />
    <property name="project.wizard.group" value="JavaFX Application" />
    <property name="project.wizard.template" value="JavaFX Application" />
    <!-- change here --><property name="file.chooser.recent.files" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Gluon/SceneBuilder.lnk&#10;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_141" />
    <property name="jdk.selected.JAVA_MODULE" value="1.8" />
    <property name="file.gist.reindex.count" value="641" />
    <property name="lastTip" value="3" />
    <property name="settings.code.style.selected.tab.JAVA" value="Tabs and Indents" />
    <property name="FileTemplates.SelectedTemplate" value="HTML File" />
  </component>
</application>
```

I found where my SceneBuilder exe is located and changed the path in both files.

other.xml

```
<application>
  <component name="JavaFxSettings">
    <!-- change here --><option name="pathToSceneBuilder" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder.exe" />
    <!-- change here --><option name="myPathToSceneBuilder" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder.exe" />
  </component>
</application>
```

options.xml

```
<application>
  <component name="PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="Default.savedEditorTheme" value="_@user_Default" />
    <property name="installed.kotlin.plugin.version" value="1.2.10-release-IJ2017.3-1" />
    <property name="project.wizard.group" value="JavaFX Application" />
    <property name="project.wizard.template" value="JavaFX Application" />
    <!-- change here --><property name="file.chooser.recent.files" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder.exe&#10;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_141" />
    <property name="jdk.selected.JAVA_MODULE" value="1.8" />
    <property name="file.gist.reindex.count" value="641" />
    <property name="lastTip" value="3" />
    <property name="settings.code.style.selected.tab.JAVA" value="Tabs and Indents" />
    <property name="FileTemplates.SelectedTemplate" value="HTML File" />
  </component>
</application>
```

Finally, I restarted IntelliJ and right clicked on the `FXML` file and selected "Open in SceneBuilder" and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaFX > Path to SceneBuilder` and select directory of `JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe`

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0):

follow the below step

Download and install scenebuilder(download same version of scene builder as your Java in your machine for eg if you have Java 8 on your local then download Scene builder version 8)

1.Open intellij -> Navigate to file -> Setting -> Type JavaFx

Set the location of scenebuilder in your local machine to the path as shown below

C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder\SceneBuilder.exe

Click apply and OK.

Now try to access scene builder from your .fxml file